# Count number of isosceles triangles in rectangle

Tags: combinatorics

> > Given $(1×49)$ rectangle partitioned into $(1×1)$ squares, how many isosceles triangles can we draw inside rectangle **such that the vertices of triangle lies on squares corners?**

Can this question be solved by combinations ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the rectangular tower is standing up. There are two kinds of isosceles triangles possible: one where they are confined to only one square ($45-45-90$ triangles) and the other kind in which they occupy more than one square.

*Kind 1*: There are $49$ squares available and in each case the triangle can be rotated in $4$ different orientations. So, we have a total of $49\cdot 4=196$ triangles.

*Kind 2*:

Two vertices will be on one side and the third on the opposite (sides meaning to the right or left). Observe that there must be an even number of squares between the two vertices on the same side, otherwise the triangle can’t be made isosceles. Now, the question is: how many ways of choosing $2,4,6,8.....48$ consecutive squares? Well, the $\#$ ways of choosing $2k$ consecutive squares out of $49$ is $49 -2k+1$, and so we simply need to sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{24} 2k = 600$$

Now, the triangles could be facing right *or* left, so multiply by $2$: 
$600\times 2=1200$

Hence, we get a total of $$196+ 1200=1396$$ isosceles triangles.